# for loop of matrix multiplications in cupy

Tags: python, cupy

I'm using [cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/index.html) and I want to know if there is any way to make the following calculation faster

```
import cupy as cp

cp.sum([cp.dot(var, cp.matmul(M, var)).item() for var in x])
```

Could parallelize with python built-in libraries but I don't know if it's the best (efficient) way to do it. My need arises from the fact that the above sum is done many times in another cycle for, moving through `x`

**EDIT**:

here `x` is an array with shape `(m, n)`, so each `var` is a 1D array of length `n`, by other hand `M` is a matrix with shape `(n,n)`.

Comment: What are M and x? What is their shape? Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Hello!, I think the shape is not important here but I edited my post. It's a quadratic function being evaluated multiples times. The problem here is that I'm doing multiple computations sequentially.